# source in seder olam of date of dor haflaga

Tags: sources-mekorot, time, parashat-noach

Where in the *sefer seder olam* does it say the year that dor haflaga/ generation of dispersion took place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first chapter.

Here it is in the Leiner edition:

> מאדם עד המבול אלף ותרנ"ו שנים, וזה פרטן, אדם ק"ל, שת ק"ה, אנוש צ', קינן ע', מהללאל ס"ה, ירד קס"ב, חנוך ס"ה, מתושלח קפ"ז, למך קפ"ב ונח בן שש מאות שנה וגו' (בראשית ז ו). חנוך קבר את אדם, וחיה אחריו נ"ז שנה, מתושלח מיצה ימיו עד המבול, **מן המבול עד הפלגה ש"מ שנה**, נמצא נח חיה אחר הפלגה עשר שנים אבינו אברהם היה בפלגה בין מ"ח שנה, אמר רבי יוסי נביא גדול היה עבר שקרא שם בנו פלג ברוח הקודש, שנאמר כי בימיו נפלגה הארץ וגו' (שם /בראשית/ י כה), אם בתחלת ימיו, והלא יקטן אחיו היה קטן ממנו והוליד י"ג משפחות ונתפלגו, ואם באמצע ימיו והלא לא בא לסתום אלא לפרש, הא אינו אומר כי בימיו נפלגה הארץ אלא בסוף ימיו

A translation might be:

> From Adam until the Flood one thousand six hundred and fifty six years, and these are the details, Adam 130 [years], Set 105, Enosh 90, Keinan 70, Mahalallel 65, Yered 162, Chanoch 65, Metuselah 187, Lemech 182 and Noah 600 years, etc.  (Genesis 7:6).   Chanoch buried Adam and lived after him for 57 years.  Metuselah lived until the Flood, **From the Flood to the "Palaga" [dor haflaga] 340 years**, it follows that Noah lived ten years past the Palaga, Abraham was 48 during the Palaga.
>
> Rabbi Yossi said:  Eber was a great prophet for he named his son "Peleg" using divine inspiration since it says "for in his days the land was *split* [the root of the Hebrew verb "to split" is pronounced "peleg"] (genesis 10:25).  It [the divide] could not have taken place at the beginning of his [Peleg's] days, for Yaktan his brother was younger and begat 13 families that were divided. It [the divide happened] could not have taken place during the middle of his [Peleg's] days, for the Torah comes to explain not to hide.   Therefore, the verse means that the divide happened at the end of his days.
>
> (Clarification: "לא בא לסתום אלא לפרש" is taken to mean that the split must have happened either in the first or last year of Peleg's life.  Since Peleg's younger brother has kids who were later divided, it couldn't have been in his first year, so it must have been in the last year of Peleg's life).

Comment: you are the best!!!

Comment: i see you are real smart! would i be able to ask you to translate an english paragraph into hebrew?! :)

Comment: @LittleMissFabulous Ah shucks. I'm blushing. You could try posting the question, and assuming it is deemed to be on topic, maybe I or someone else will be able to help. I warn you, however, a) it will likely be off-topic. b) My skills probably wont be up to the job. c) I likely wont have the time anyway.

Comment: well, i guess i must rely on the horrific translation of google translate... :)

Comment: @Nic I dont think (s)he wanted this translated into English; (s)he wanted a different, English paragrpah translated into Hebrew. You should certainly be commended for your kindness, though.

Comment: @mevaqesh whoops!

Comment: @Nic I repeat that your kindness is nonetheless commendable.

Comment: @mevaqesh you can check my library for Seder Olam The Rabbinic View of Biblical Chronology its in folder 3